# Cannot use import statement outside a module calling values from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

Unable to Resolve the Import issue, already have type = module added in package.json file

```html
import { env, username, password, panel } from "../DemoAutomationProject/config";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

[![testcase.jsfile][1]][1]

[image: configjs file]

Unable to solve this import error

[image: dependencies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong while you are importing baseConfig.You have access to the function only but not the local variables to the function. You need to return an object which you consume later.

```
async function baseConfig() {
 ///
}

module.export;


import { env, username, password, panel } from "../DemoAutomationProject/config";
```

**Solution:**
you need to import the function baseConfig. It will returns you the
object having all the data.

```
    async function baseConfig() {
     return {
       env: '',
       username: '',
       password: '',
       panel: '',
    }

module.export = baseConfig;
```

Now in import do this.

```
const config = require('../../DemoAutomationProject/config');
config().then(data => {
 const { env, username, password, panel } = data;   
});
```

Comment: `return  {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'` getting this error @deepak  and if call return `async function baseConfig() {
     {
       env: '',
       username: '',
       password: '',
       panel: '',
    }

module.export;

Comment: Oh , I have updated the code. Async function return promise so we need to use then to get the data.

Comment: `TypeError: conf is not a function`  still getting this error with below code @deepak `const conf = require('../DemoAutomationProject/config');   conf().then(data => {
 const { env, username, password } = data;   
});`

Comment: My Requirement is to Keep the Config information "config.js" in one File and Used these base values in all the other files testcase1.js and testcase2.js like wise

Comment: check module.export. it should be module.export= baseConfig

Comment: why it is async function. It should be a normal function as you are hardcoding the value. In that case it will be normal (remove async from baseConfig).

 const { env, username, password, panel } = config();

Comment: Thanks deepak didnt needed `config().then(data => {
 const { env, username, password, panel } = data;   
}); ` btw what is this statement for ?   - > This works `module.export = baseConfig;` in base config file and `const config = require('../DemoAutomationProject/config.js');` in main file Thanks @deepak

Comment: you need to tell what you are going to export from this file.